# How to fit fxml file to ChildAnchorPane ?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm working on my project which is having two **fxml** files, i managed to open both fxml files from MainController in both ways like

> Both the actions performed by clicking on Button

1. creating and opening new stage,scene and loading fxml file.
2. replacing child AnchorPane with fxml.

Problem is in second way: fxml file won't fit according to the child Anchor Pane which I've already defined in my Main FXML file with coordinates , its appears on top left corner of the primaryStage and is there any way i can fix this problem ?

Please follow the screen shot which explains the GUI view of my application.
[image]

> MainController.java

```
@FXML
private Button okay;
@FXML
private AnchorPane HostScreen,MainScreen;
class NewStage{
    NewStage() throws IOException{
        Stage subStage = new Stage();
        subStage.setTitle("Connect To MySQL Host");
        HostScreen = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SQLHostWindow.fxml"));
        Scene HostScene = new Scene(HostScreen,640,400);
        subStage.setScene(HostScene);
        subStage.centerOnScreen();
        subStage.show();
    }
}
class NewScene{
    NewScene() throws IOException{
        HostScreen = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SQLHostWindow.fxml"));
        MainScreen.getChildren().set(0, HostScreen);
        System.out.println(MainScreen.getChildren().get(0));
    }
}

@FXML
public void OpenHostScreen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    new NewStage();
    new NewScene();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's absolute nonsense to use constructors of inner classes to modify the scene, unless those classes have some other functionality. In this case you just create objects for no real reason. Instead the functionality should be moved to methods, e.g.

```
void replaceChild() throws IOException{
    HostScreen = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SQLHostWindow.fxml"));
    MainScreen.getChildren().set(0, HostScreen);
    System.out.println(MainScreen.getChildren().get(0));
}

@FXML
public void OpenHostScreen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    replaceChild();
}
```

Furthermore you cannot expect the layout parameters of the original node to simply be transfered to the replacement node just because you replace the node. `Pane`s often store layout properties inside the `properties` map of the child node. The contents of this map are not automatically copied.

Also there are some properties of the child `Node` that could be relevant for the parent depending on it's type and the parameters stored in the `properties`:

- `layoutX`, `layoutY` (in case they are not determined by the parent)
- `managed`
- Translate, Rotate, Scale
- size
- ...

In this case you most likely only need to copy the anchors, size and position, which can be done by copying the properties and assigning `layoutX`, `layoutY`, `prefWidth` and `prefHeight`.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Region back = new Region();
    back.relocate(10, 10);
    back.setPrefSize(590, 390);
    back.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(back, 10d);
    // AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(back, 10d);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(back, 10d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(back, 10d);

    Button btn = new Button("Change");

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(back, btn);

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        // replace first child of root with new one; keep anchors & position/size
        Region region = new Region();
        region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        Node oldRegion = root.getChildren().set(0, region);

        // copy properties from old map
        Map<Object, Object> properties = region.getProperties();
        oldRegion.getProperties().forEach((k, v) -> properties.putIfAbsent(k, v));

        // copy position & set pref size to size of replaced node
        region.relocate(oldRegion.getLayoutX(), oldRegion.getLayoutX());
        Bounds bounds = oldRegion.getLayoutBounds();
        region.setPrefSize(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```